# (HTML/CSS/JS) Having trouble adding buttons to an h2 using createElement() and appendChild()

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, createelement, createtextnode

I am working on a website in which you can add items to a list of books you want to read and then press a button to review it. You can also press a different button to delete the item. Things were working fine until I got to adding the aforementioned buttons. Once I started adding the code for them, the items that would previously be added to the webpage weren't showing up. I am using createElement() and appendChild() methods. I was hoping for the buttons to be appended next to the other text that I put on the h2. But now nothing shows up at all. I've tried to reorder the code and I've checked the variables multiple times, but I can't find the source of the issue at all. I would appreciate any help in finding this reason.

I'm using replit.com

```js
// listens for a click on the "add new" button
document.getElementById("new").addEventListener("click", newBook);
let newdiv = document.getElementById("newdiv");

// takes information about a new list item
function newBook() {
  // reveals the input boxes needed
  newdiv.style.display = "inline-block";
}

// listens for a click on the "add" button
document.getElementById("enternew").addEventListener("click", addItem);

// creates a new list item and adds it to the body of the webpage
function addItem() {
  // defines the new element as an h2 element
  let item = document.createElement("h2");

  // gets the variable values from the user's input
  let bookname = document.getElementById("book").value;
  let authorname = document.getElementById("author").value;
  let seriesname = document.getElementById("series").value;

  // converts the user's input into text nodes
  let b = document.createTextNode(bookname);
  let a = document.createTextNode(", by " + authorname);
  let s = document.createTextNode(" (" + seriesname + ")");

  // creates buttons to initiate the review process and remove the list item
  let review = document.createElement("button");
  let remove = document.createElement("button");

  // creates a text node for the review button and appends it to the button element
  let rv = document.createTextNode("REVIEW");
  review.appendChild(rv);

  // creates a text node for the remove button and appends it to the button element
  let rm = document.createTextNode("✖");
  remove.appendChild(rm);

  // appends the text nodes to the h2 element
  item.appendChild(b);
  item.appendChild(a);
  item.appendChild(s);

  // appends the buttons to the h2 element
  item.appendChild("review");
  item.appendChild("remove");

  // adds the h2 element, including all the text nodes, to the body of the webpage
  document.body.appendChild(item);

  review.onclick = function() {
    alert("test");
  }

  remove.onclick = function() {
    alert("test 2");
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D2AB8B;
}

.header {
  font-family: "Cutive Mono";
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-style: dashed;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: #413013;
}

p {
  font-family: "EB Garamond";
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #413013;
}

.df {
  border-width: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "EB Garamond";
  background-color: #FFF6E3;
  color: #413013;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ACD9DC;
  border-width: 0px;
}

#newdiv {
  display: none;
}

input {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Cutive Mono";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Reading List</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive Mono">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB Garamond">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <!-- page header -->
    <h1 class="header">~ YOUR READING LIST ~</h1>
    <br/> <br/>
    <!-- add new section for new book entry -->
    <button class="df" id="new">ADD NEW +</button>
    <br/>

    <!-- hidden division that contains input fields to add a new entry -->
    <div id="newdiv">
      <p>Book name:</p>
      <input id="book" />
      <br/>
      <p>Author name:</p>
      <input id="author" />
      <br/>
      <p>Series name (optional):</p>
      <input id="series" />
      <br/> <br/>
      <button class="df" id="enternew">ADD</button>
    </div>
  </center>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge-v2.js" theme="teal" position="bottom-right"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `item.appendChild("review");` you probably didn’t want those quotes.

Comment: As James pointed out, in your `appendChild()` methods, you are placing quotes around your defined variable names `review` and `remove`, this will break the code for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the console. `"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."`

You're trying to append strings when you meant to do this

```
item.appendChild(review);
item.appendChild(remove);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for helping me find my issue :)